# tf.keras Custom Callback to reduce overfitting which save model weights IFF (val_lass < loss) & (val_loss < min_val_loss)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

How can I build a Custom Callback in Keras which gives me the **BEST** out of training. In both of `ModelCheckPoint` and `EarlyStopping`, I can stop the model and save weights but it only looks at the `val_loss` most of the time and does not consider the overfitting part while training. I want to build a custom callback which takes into account the minimum validation loss that has ever reached, current validation loss and the current training loss.

I want this callback to **Save the weights if the validation loss is less that training loss and it is less than the minimum validation loss that has ever occured**. With this, I think I won't have to to use any of the above two and I can be sure that no matter how much I run my model, it won't ever overfit.

I can use the `keras.callbacks.Callback` as a base class for my model.
and access the current loss, current validation loss as:

```
current_loss = logs.get("loss")
current_val_loss = logs.get("val_loss")
```

```
class NoOverfit(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, patience=0):
        super(NoOverfit, self).__init__():


    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        
        self.min_val_loss = np.Inf

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_loss = logs.get("loss")
        current_val_loss = logs.get("val_loss")
        if np.less(current_val_loss, current_loss) & np.less(current_val_loss, self.min_val_loss):
            self.min_val_loss = current_val_loss
        
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
            # how do I save weights now?
```

but I'm unable to wrap my head around it how can put it into code that it works and going through the  [tensorflow documentation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback) did not help me either.

Comment: `EarlyStopping` does the exact same thing, get rid of this new class and by default patience is set to 0 which implies, it won't save unless you have a better model

Comment: I think you are missing the whole part here. Neither of the `EarlyStopping` and `ModelCheckPoint` considers the comparison between `validation_loss` and `loss`. They chek whether the model has improved in terms of less loss. Less `val_loss` does not reflect that model is not overfit. last epoch's `val_loss` could 0.3 with loss=0.4 but next time `val_loss` could be 0.25 but `loss`=0.1. IT means the model has started overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with a margin = 0.02

```
class EarlyStoppingAtOverfitt(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if logs.get("val_loss") > logs.get("loss") + 0.02 :
            self.stopped_epoch = epoch
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

From : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback